# Optimize this simple SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that uses dblink to backfill data from one database and insert it into a jsonb column in another database. It only needs to run on 1000 records or so, but it takes a long time to run (between 30s to a minute).

Why? How do I make this faster?

Here is the query:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
update "table" t1 set jsonb_example_column = jsonb_set(jsonb_example_column, '{user}', jsonb_build_object('name',jsonb_example_column->'user'->'name','phone',jsonb_example_column->'user'->'phone','address',jsonb_example_column->'user'->'address','user_id', other_db.user_id)) 
FROM dblink('dbname=$DB_NAME
            port=$DB_PORT
            host=$DB_HOST
            user=$DB_USER
            password=$DB_PASSWORD',
            'SELECT user_id, external_id from other_db_table t2')
AS other_db("user_id" uuid, external_id uuid) WHERE other_db.external_id = t1.external_id;"
```

Comment: It's a remote table, so check: a) network connection to remote server,  b) amount of requested data. If you request a lot of data by slow connection - then nothing unexpected here

Comment: Did you try if using a foreign table is faster?

Comment: "It only needs to run on 1000". Is that the size of "other_db_table"?  If not, where does that number come from?

Comment: I have not tried a foreign table, but will do so.  and yes, ~1000 is the size of  "other_db_table".

Comment: So the foreign table was much faster. Thanks, a_horse_with_no_name!

Answer (score 1):

Answer is thanks to a_horse_with_no_name, but here is the optimized query that now takes a third of the time:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER user FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host '0.0.0.0', port '5432', dbname 'user');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER user OPTIONS (user 'your_foreign_db_user', password 'your_foreign_db_password');
GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER user TO postgres;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foreign_table(user_id uuid, external_id uuid) SERVER user OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'foreign_db_table');

UPDATE "local_db_table" lt SET jsonb_example_column = jsonb_set(jsonb_example_column, '{user}', jsonb_build_object('name',jsonb_example_column->'user'->'name','phone',jsonb_example_column->'user'->'phone','address',jsonb_example_column->'user'->'address','user_id', ft.user_id))
FROM foreign_table AS ft WHERE lt.external_id = ft.external_id;
```